# Is there a way to show a table from another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to show a table from another website. For example the table I want to have is on example.com with the id table". And in my html I have a div in which I want too show the table with the id table. And I have really no idea how I have to do this. I have already looked into other questions. But that answers didn't work for me. And I have also read something about "file_get_contents" but I don't know how I can get a specific id with that.

Comment: Hi, There is yet no way to show specific table from another website, you can but use IFRAME for page.

Comment: @Annshuk I disagree. You can use ajax to load the page on another website and distinguish it from other elements through query.

Comment: yes it can be through Ajax but for specific table id m not sure, or do you have any demo example for this.

Comment: Will a theoretical answer, describing the steps, be okay, and do you use ASP or PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>This is the API for the `.load()` method. It is a jQuery ajax function. It has the ability to load content after the current page is finished loading.</s>

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Using this code will help load the `#table` into `#target`. Please notice that **ajax will not work locally for some browsers, e.g. Chrome. It should be tested on a server if local webpages doesn't work.**

```
$("#target").load("http://example.com #table");
```

### Scratch that

Thanks to **charlietfl**, who pointed out that you need CORS to request data. I have to be honest, I am not familiar with this but have dealt with it before. Here I compiled some code that might help you:

```js
$(function() {
 function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
 }
  var req = createCORSRequest("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript");
  if (req) {
   req.onload = function(data) {
     console.log(data);
      var full = data.target.response;
     $("#target").html($(full).find("#firstHeading"));
    };
    req.send();
 }
})
```

```css
#target {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This will request the title of the Wikipedia's page using the help of https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com</p>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

I am really not familiar with CORS, but I guess the basic idea is the destination server have to agree that the origin is safe before sending data. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This will fail due to *same origin policy*. Answer is incomplete regarding cross domain issues

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for pointing that out. I am not familiar with that. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Using $.ajax() JQuery method with dataType:"jsonp", you can update/add a table with their id. For this you have enable cross domain access to site from where you want data. For this you need to use server side language like C#,PHP, or other to site from where you want data. If You are using asp.net technology, then you can follow the link http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/JAVAScript/AJAX/Cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-JSONP/20154