# parsing table of emergency numbers from wikipedia

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am trying to write a javascript snippet to parse the data from the tables on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emergency_telephone_numbers

I found dbpedia which seems promising, but it seems as if their system ignores the tables:
https://dbpedia.org/describe/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FList_of_emergency_telephone_numbers&invfp=IFP_OFF&sas=SAME_AS_OFF&sid=868

Does anybody know an alternative way to parse the data.

Comment: Country names seems to be always in the first cell of each row between `a` tags and the numbers seems to be withing `b` tags in the following cells

Comment: Maybe it can be usefull
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841650/how-to-get-html-table-values-from-external-website/54841762   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694415/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-table-from-another-website

Answer (score 0):

python to the rescue, I couldn't find an easy way to do this in javascript but in python.

I found an easier to parse table here: https://www.adducation.info/general-knowledge-travel-and-transport/emergency-numbers/
But it is still an html table and I want to use it in Javascript, so JSON is easier.
This code solves my problem:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html("emergency_numbers.html")[0]
json_data = data.to_json(orient="records")
with open("emergency_numbers.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json_data)
```

result is:

```
  [ { 'Country / Territory'            : '\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddeb Afghanistan'
    , '\u260e Emergency'               : null
    , '\u260e Police'                  : '119'
    , '\u260e Ambulance'               : '119, 102'
    , '\u260e Fire'                    : '112, 119'
    , 'Group'                          : 'Asia'
    , 'Calling codes'                  : '+93'
    , 'Local emergency numbers & info' : 'You can dial 020 112 from mobile but only in Kabul.'
    } 
  , { 'Country / Territory'            : '\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf1 Albania'
    , '\u260e Emergency'               : null
    , '\u260e Police'                  : '129'
    , '\u260e Ambulance'               : '127'
    , '\u260e Fire'                    : '128'
    , 'Group'                          : 'Europe'
    , 'Calling codes'                  : '+355'
    , 'Local emergency numbers & info' : null
    } 
  , { 'Country / Territory'            : '\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddff Algeria'
    , '\u260e Emergency'               : null
    , '\u260e Police'                  : '17'
    , '\u260e Ambulance'               : '14'
    , '\u260e Fire'                    : '14'
    , 'Group'                          : 'Africa'
    , 'Calling codes'                  : '+213'
    , 'Local emergency numbers & info' : 'Dial 1548 for tourist police.'
    } 
  , { 'Country / Territory'            : '\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf8 American Samoa'
    , '\u260e Emergency'               : '911'
    , '\u260e Police'                  : null
    , '\u260e Ambulance'               : null
    , '\u260e
```